# Special parameters in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

According to this tutorial the under the section "Special parameters" (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) the following unusual function definition should be valid:

```
def test_special(pos1, pos2, /, pos_or_kwd, *, kwd1, kwd2):
    print("in test_special")
    print("pos1: " + pos1)
    print("pos2: " + pos2)
    print("pos_or_kwd: " + pos_or_kwd)
    print("kwd1: " + kwd1)
    print("kwd2: " + kwd2)
```

However I get the error:

```
$ python TestArgs.py
  File "TestArgs.py", line 11
    def test_special(pos1, pos2, /, pos_or_kwd, *, kwd1, kwd2):
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm using Python version 3.7.5.

Comment: That was added in 3.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/` in the list of parameters in a function definition is a new syntax allwoed from Python 3.8.0 and forward.

It is a SyntaxError in Python 3.7